# Response from AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, image

This is something I've done several times, however using the same method it now won't work.
This is a simple image upload script whereby it posts to some PHP for processing and I want the PHP to output the filename to be read by the JS.

Here is my jQuery:

```
$(function(){
  $('#photoimg').change(function(){
    var formData = new FormData($('#img_form')[0]);
    var wHeight = $(window).height();
    // get height of browser
    var wWidth =  $(window).width();
    // get width of browser
    $('#loading').show();
    $.ajax({
      url: '../_process/calendar_upload.php?w='+ wWidth +'&h='+ wHeight +'',
      //send browser height and width to scale temp image to fit to screen
      type: 'POST',
      success: function (resp) {
        $('#loading').hide();
        //write scaled image to popup
        var fname = resp.imgname;
        $("#cal_imageuploader").html("<img src='../_img/event_images/'"+ fname +" '/>");
        //loads temp image into popup for cropping
        $('#cal_imageuploader').bPopup();
        //opens popup
        //trigger cropping on photo
      },
      data: formData,
      cache: false,
      contentType: false,
      processData: false
    });
  });
});
```

And the PHP it's being posted to:

```
<?php
  $session_id = mysql_escape_string($_COOKIE['Foo']);
  // User session id
  $path = "../_img/event_images/";
  $tmp_path = "../_img/tmp";
  $wHeight = $_REQUEST['h'];
  $wWidth = $_REQUEST['w'];
  $valid_formats = array("jpg", "png", "gif", "bmp", "jpeg");
  if (isset($_POST) and $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST") {
    $name = $_FILES['photoimg']['name'];
    $size = $_FILES['photoimg']['size'];
    if (strlen($name)) {
      list($txt, $ext) = explode(".", $name);
      if (in_array($ext, $valid_formats)) {
        if ($size < (3024 * 3024)) {
        // Image size max 3 MB
          $hash = "49esd34h";
          $randstring = rand(5, 10);
          $actual_image_name = $session_id."_".sha1($name . $hash . $randstring) . "." . $ext;
          $tmp = $_FILES['photoimg']['tmp_name'];
          //tmp file code goes here
          if (move_uploaded_file($tmp, $path . $actual_image_name)) {
            $resp['imgname'] = $actual_image_name;
            echo json_encode($resp);
          } else
            echo "failed";
        } else
          echo "Image too large...";
      } else
        echo "Invalid file format...";
    } else
      echo "Please select image..!";
    exit;
  }
?>
```

Currently the var `fname` is undefined and I can't think why. Any ideas?

Comment: Of course you have check your console and network tab and you see no error otherwise you would have post it, right?

Comment: Yeah checked console and the only thing I see is that the var fname is undeffined. Which is whats bugging me.

Comment: try `console.log(resp)` and see what response you get from the server.

Comment: @Spokey I get the fname in JSON format. "{"imgname":"29_6e9abc38337eb07674042162435683128f0aecae.jpg"}"

Comment: does it work if you remove `fname` and use `<img src='../_img/event_images/'"+ resp.imgname +" '/>` ?

Comment: Haha - Worked, so simple! Hate it when its like that. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try by specifying  `dataType : 'json'` in ajax

```
$.ajax({
      url: '../_process/calendar_upload.php?w='+ wWidth +'&h='+ wHeight +'',
      //send browser height and width to scale temp image to fit to screen
      type: 'POST',
      dataType : 'json',
      success: function (resp) {
        $('#loading').hide();
        //write scaled image to popup
        var fname = resp.imgname;
        $("#cal_imageuploader").html("<img src='../_img/event_images/'"+ fname +" '/>");
        //loads temp image into popup for cropping
        $('#cal_imageuploader').bPopup();
        //opens popup
        //trigger cropping on photo
      },
      data: formData,
      cache: false,
      contentType: false,
      processData: false
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

i think the response object doesnt have imgname.

I guess the $actual_image_name is not getting any value , can you check the value of the variable.

Comment: $actual_image_name is correct - I've checked to make sure the file is uploaded and renamed correctly, which it is. So it's nothing there... its just getting it back to the jQuery! Grr!